# телеграмм бот, когда в тг пишешь город то в консоли выдает ошибку TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Tags: строки, telebot, type-error, tuple, pyowm

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message,):
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']

    answer = 'В городе', message.text, 'сейчас', w.detailed_status, '\n'
    answer += 'Температура на сегодняшний час:',temp,'℃ ', '\n\n'

    if temp < -10:
        answer +='Сейчас холодно, зима на дворе, а что ты хотел?      ps. шапку накинь'

    elif temp < -5:
        answer +='на улице прохладно, без куртки не выходи'

    elif temp < -15:
        answer +='ЁмаЁ дубак на улице, теплее оденься'

    else:
        answer +='Темп норм, по крайней мере не зима)'
```

Comment: приучайся читать текст ошибки (полностью, а не только то, что ты сюда скопировал) и понимать его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что после `answer = 'В городе', message.text, 'сейчас', w.detailed_status, '\n'` в `answer` находится не строка, а кортеж.